# usage of "effect of"

Tags: word-usage

[From the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/effect)

> This drug may have **the effect of speeding up** your heart rate.

I guess it means that the drug results in speeding up heart rate.

> The medicine had the effect of making me sleepy.

Similarly, the medicine results in user sleepy.

Both of them use a pattern like `A has the effect of X`, where A represents the reason/cause and X represents the result.

However, this one seems more complicated.

> The effect of the redundancies on morale has been extremely damaging

the pattern becomes `A has the effect of X on Y` and A is omitted, is my understanding correct?

Comment: The redundancies have had the effect of damaging morale. So A is 'the redundancies'.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you. That's another reason I ask the OP. Is the thing right after "effect of" the result or the cause? Perhaps, X is the result of A and the cause of Y at the same time, is my understanding correct?

Comment: In this sentence, the thing after _effect_ is the cause. 'The effect of A  on morale has been X' (or you could say that X is 'damage to morale').

Comment: @KateBunting I guess "extremely damaging" is not X, as X is some kind of a thing. In contrast, "extremely damaging" is an adjective to describe the extent of that effect.

Answer (score 0):

Redundancy = A
Damaged moral = X

So, following the syntax of your example, we can say that The effect of A has been X